# nginx redirects every http request to https

Tags: http, redirect, ssl, https, nginx

finally i switched to the nginx webserver. But everytime i access for example `http://mywebsite.com` it redirects me to `https://mywebsite.com`. I dont have any ssl options in my server block (vhost). Here a stripped down version (only removed help comments):

```
server {
        listen 80;
        root /usr/share/nginx/www/mywebsite/htdocs;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        server_name mywebsite.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param CONTEXT Staging;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

I don't really know if i am on the correct place to search for the bug?!

PS: PHP returns me `["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]=> string(8) "HTTP/1.1"`

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! I've found in my `/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params` that line `fastcgi_param  HTTPS                   $https;` which i commented out. Now, it works fine. Hope that helps someone else.